# How to initialize the NSArray in ARC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, nsarray

I tried initializing the array :

In .h file

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *accounts;
```

In .m file :

```
    @synthesize accounts;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       NSArray *arrList = [acAccountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];  
       // This returns array
       self.accounts = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrList]; // I tried debug after 
       // this and it gives me data in debugger.  
       // Note array List have 3 data in it.   
       }
```

Now On button click i call a method:

```
- (IBAction) ButtonClicked :(id) sender {
      NSLog(@" data : %@",[self.accounts objectAtIndex:0]); // Breaks at this point. 
      //  When i tried with debug it gives me (no Objective-C description available)
}
```

Is the initialization of array correct Or If the code is not right please let me know.

Main concern  is when i do debug in viewDidLoad, the self.accounts show me proper values. But after doing the click event its empty and throws EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: i didnt got you.  Can you explain me again ?

Comment: Show me the initialization of arrList

Answer (score 0):

hm looks fine. A couple of questions then:

Where are you calling the `self.accounts = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrList];`
I assume that the array is being setup before your button is being pressed?

There's no real reason that arc should be clearing out the variable. Have you set a strong reference to it or a weak one? If you're using `self.` on a variable, you should have :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *accounts;
```

or similar to that in the .h file and then

```
@synthesize accounts;
```

in the .m file.

If you've got `weak` instead of `strong` then ARC may possibly clear the memory but it still shouldn't.

Comment: Hey Yes, i am initializing array on my viewDidload and also i have defined the propery as (nonatomic, retain).  I will update my code

Comment: Out of curiosity, try using `self.accounts = [arrList copy];` and see if anything changes?

Comment: What error is xCode giving you? Is it saying that the array doesn't have any data in it when you try to access it, or does it give you some other error?

Comment: Where is your definition of the account store? `acAccountStore`? Make that a @property as well. The objects in your array are probably pointing to it. If it's being released then those objects are pointing to empty memory.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Create a property for your account store as well.  I had this exact issue recently and this fixed it.

`@property (nonatomic, strong) ACAccountStore *accountStore;`

**Original Answer**

Because you're using `ARC`, you need to change your property declaration from

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *accounts;
```

to:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *accounts;
```

With the latest LLVM compiler, you don't need to synthesize properties either.  So you can remove `@synthesize accounts`.

You should always use defensive coding as well, so in your `- buttonClicked:` method, you should do:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (self.accounts) {
          NSLog(@"data: %@", [self.accounts objectAtIndex:0]);
    }
}
```

This makes sure that the pointer to the array is valid.

You can also check to make sure an item in an array exists before trying to read it by doing:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (self.accounts.count > 0)
          NSLog(@"data: %@", [self.accounts objectAtIndex:0]);
    }
 }
```